# Django referencing urls between apps

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a project which has just assimilated several apps from other projects of mine to one main project. The structure is one main app that lies at the root url and other apps with specific urls. I have set up my urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', include('main_app.urls')),
url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
url(r'^app3/', include('app3.urls')),
```

I have a model in my main_app models.py which describes my other apps along the lines of:

```
class App(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField("App Image", upload_to="images/apps/", blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

And in my main_app views:

```
def index(request):
    app_list = App.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',
            locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So, in my root index template (main_app) I want to cycle through all apps and print a link:

```
{% for app in app_list %}
    {{ some_app_variables }}
    <a href="???">Link to app</a>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how should I define this link. Should I have a get_absolute_url for the app model?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app doesn't inherently have some URL associated with it. URLs are tied to views, and those views could reference any model from any app or no models or apps at all for that matter. What's you're doing doesn't make sense.

**UPDATE:** I'm still unsure about what you're linking to. An "app" is an abstract concept. I understand having a list of "Apps", but what kind of view would you get for an individual app? Still, yes, you should have a `get_absolute_url` method on your `Apps` model. Then, your best bet would be to name whatever view in each app is going to be the "index" view something along the lines of "app_(title)". Then you can construct the right reverse with something along the lines of:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('app_%s' % self.title, (), {})
```

Of course, you should probably modify that with something akin to a slug to accommodate titles that might have multiple words, e.g. "Cool App" would need to be replaced with something like "cool_app".

Like I said, though, what you're trying to accomplish still doesn't make much sense from where I'm sitting.

Comment: I have added some info on my models and views which should hopefully clarify what I would like to do.

Comment: That is more along the lines I was thinking. I am sure I must be explaining myself badly though as I would guess that this is a fundamental question for any project with multiple applications. To put it another way how would you link to each of your applications from a central homepage, without hard-coding the urls in the template?

Comment: See, the issue is that apps aren't typically treated as so defined. You might have a calendar app on your site, but you don't link to the "app" you create a view in that app that knows how to render a calendar and then you attach a URL such as "/calendar/" to that view. The app could be called "calendar" or "events" or "dogfood". It doesn't really matter. It's just a container for a defined set of functionality.

Comment: Yes, that has been my typical use case, but for this project I have several apps which do quite different things and have separate databases, but do have to share a site and I want to be able to share data between the databases. For this motivation I am rolling my developed apps into a single project with database aliasing. However each app has its own urls, views and templates.

Comment: That doesn't really matter. You simply include each app's urls.py in the project's urls.py tying them to a base url, e.g. a calendar app would likely be included at '/calendar/'. Then, all URLs within would be under that URL prefix. Once handling has been passed off the the appropriate view, nothing else matters. You can use models from any and all apps, have custom templates even make the site look completely different.